# Ssh and ipv6: resolution

Tags: ssh, ipv6

On my /etc/hosts i made some ipv6address

```
fe80::ee01          hpux.ipv6.private      hpux
fe80::ee03          slack64.ipv6.private    slack64
```

I do

```
ssh -6 fe80::ee01%br0 OK
```

if I do

```
  ssh -6 hpux%br0
```

give me error

and also

```
ssh hpux%br0
```

give error.
No way to use ipv6 hostname?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give real addresses to your hosts. `fe80:` addresses are link-local and they are nice for automatic protocols (mDNS, DHCPv6 etc) but not for normal use. Use the global IPv6 addresses you got from your ISP. If your ISP doesn't support IPv6 yet then find a better ISP. I realise that this might not be possible for everybody.

An alternative is to generate your own ULA prefix, for example on http://unique-local-ipv6.com/ or https://www.sixxs.net/tools/grh/ula/. You won't be able to reach the internet with ULA addresses, but they are great if you want to get experience with the protocol.

Comment: I'm a little confusing about addresses,on hp-ux netconf and on the net i found fe80::* address only,where i can found "real addresses " examples?

Comment: Works fine with address like this  2001:cdba::3257:9652 Thanks

Comment: You'll need to configure them yourself. The link local addresses are always automatically there, but not suited to your use case. Easiest quick-start: Generate a ULA prefix, take the first /64 from it and configure addresses from that /64 on your device interfaces.

Comment: And don't just use other people's addresses! Use ULA addresses like I told you.

Comment: Ok,was only for testing

Comment: I gave +1 for giving good advice, but this answer does not really explain _why_ giving hostnames to link-local addresses does not work.

Comment: It doesn't work because the hosts file is system-wide but link-local addresses are per interface. There is no way to specify the scope/interface in the hosts file, and without that link-local addresses are meaningless